# на хостинге на работает htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Приветствую всех вошедших )

Локально использую OpenServer + следующий htaccess файл

```
//обновил #2, после мудрых советов!
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?my=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Все просто, нужные ЧПУ преобразуются в переменной

```
$_GET['my']

mysite.ru/about/contact -> $_GET['my'] = /about/contact
```

Локально настройки OpenServer

```
Apache-PHP-7-x64 ( PHP-7.0-x64 + MySQL-5.7-x64 )
```

На сервере те же настройки Апача/PHP. Если зайти на сайт, все норм, но если начать переходить в разделы

```
Not Found
The requested URL /about/contact was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at mysite.ru Port 80
```

Господа, подскажите как решить? Честно скажу, только изучаю ЧПУ, и не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: AllowOverrride All

Comment: в htaccess дописали? В конфиг виртуалхоста в Directory. Только туда @gforce

Comment: `RewriteBase /` после `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: обновил htaccess (выше описал) - ошибка не поменялась. ест-но пере запускал апач. прям в растеренности. локально работает, на хосте нет. ошибка - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Comment: Оберните все строки с `Rewrite...` условием `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` ... `</IfModule>`

Comment: обновил #2 та же ошибка.  перестал работать сам сайт, после правки AllowOverrride All. что странно

Comment: Я дико прошу прощения, но у меня описка. AllowOverride с двумя r, а не с тремя, конечно же.

Comment: ввел a2enmod rewrite - помогло! Обоим спасибо огромнейшее. Влепите пожалуйста инструкцию в ответ. Может кому кроме меня помежет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **.htaccess**

При работе с файлом `.htacсess` необходимо убедиться, что `Apache` обрабатывает этот файл. Для этого в конфигурации виртуального хоста (либо конфигурации самого сервера, если виртуальные хосты отсутствуют) должна быть определена директива `AllowOverride`. Эта директива должна располагаться только в конфиге и только в контексте `<Directory>`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-server
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-server
    ...
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

> После изменения конфига не забываем о рестарте Apache.

2. **RewriteEngine**

Для работы с механизмом `rewrite` к Apache обязательно должен быть подключен модуль `mod_rewrite`.

Например, так (RedHat, CentOS, Oracle Linux и т.д.):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

или так (Debian, Ubuntu и т.д.):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Дебиановское наследие также предлагает утилиты по включению/отключению модулей Apache (a2enmod, a2dismod - enable or disable an apache2 module):

```
root@ubuntu:/# a2enmod rewrite
```

> После изменения конфига не забываем о рестарте Apache.